# Coloring bug with Vim's ctermbg; workaround with VimLeave?

Tags: vim, putty, vim-syntax-highlighting

I recently discovered Vim colorschemes, and in the process have discovered a rather curious bug: when I run `hi Normal ctermbg` in Vim, the color change carries over to the shell that I'm running Vim in, like so:

[image: vim-ctermbg-bug]

I'm using PuTTYtray (but also see the behavior in PuTTY) with 256 colors enabled , bolded text indicated by font changes, and $TERM set to "putty-256color"; my .vimrc is as follows:

```
set t_Co=256
colors zenburn
```

and zenburn.vim can be found [here](https://github.com/jnurmine/Zenburn/blob/master/colors/zenburn.vim). I've isolated the problem specifically to specifically line 298, where it first configures `ctermbg` for Normal highlighting.

(As an aside: it seems that when using PuTTY tray with specific color settings, in Normal highlighting, `ctermbg` has to be first set simultaneously with `guifg` or `guibg`, e.g. `hi Normal guifg=#dcdccc ctermbg=237`, and only after that will `hi Normal ctermbg=some_val` work.)

Does anyone happen to have any idea why this is happening?

---

I've also tried to do a workaround by running `hi Normal ctermbg=None` on `VimLeave` (although I recognize that this is problematic if I run multiple Vim instances, so if anyone can suggest an alternative that would also be welcome), but with no success. Adding the following to my `.vimrc` does not work:

```
function! RESET_ctermbg()
    "reset $ctermbg to None"
    exec "hi Normal ctermbg=None"
endfunction
au VimLeave * call RESET_ctermbg()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by changing `$TERM` to `xterm-256color`; my best bet is that `putty-256color` is not well-supported enough as a shell to handle behavior like the vim colorscheme I was doing, so I don't even need to try to make the workaround work anymore.

Comment: Having `$TERM` set to `putty-256color` termcap information is installed in the Linux system where you are running vim and that that information matches the putty version and configuration flags you're using.